# Bijection between matrices in $M_{m,n}(F)$ and the linear maps $F^n \mapsto F^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

My book builds a bijection between $M_{m,n}(F)$ and the linear maps $F^n \mapsto F^m$ by proving two facts:

> 1. If $X,Y \in F^n$ and $A, B \in M_{m,n}(F)$ then: for all $X \in F^n$ we have $AX = BX \implies A = B; $
> 2. Let $\varphi: F^n \mapsto F^m$ be a linear map. There is a unique matrix $A \in M_{m,n}(F)$ s.t. $\varphi(X) = AX.$

I've two questions.

1. Why does part (1) imply uniqueness for part (ii)?
2. Is there a proof of this without using the column trick (e.g. the book proves (1) for example by saying we have $Ae_i = Be_i$ so ith column of $A$ is equal to the ith column of $B$, so $A=B$)?

Comment: (1) seems strange. I think you meant $Ax=Bx$ for all $x$ forces $A=B$.

Comment: @eranreches That's correct. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $\phi(X) = AX = BX$ for all $X \in F^n$ then clearly $(1)$ implies that $A=B$. For part $(1)$ it suffices to show that if $A(X) = 0 $ for all $X \in F^n$ then $A = 0$. Suppose if $A \not= 0$, then atleast one of its row will be non-zero vector say $R_i$. So take $X = R_i^T$ which gives us that $i^{th}$ term of $A(X) = (\mid \mid (R_i^T) \mid \mid )^2$ which should be non-zero as $R_i$ is non-zero vector. This is a contradiction to our assumption that $A(X) = 0$ for all $X$.

Comment: Thanks. Could I ask, why does it suffice to show that $A(X) = 0 \implies A=0$? I know if this wasn't the case then map wouldn't be one to one, but I'm not sure how to tie it to $AX = BX$. Also, what does the notation $(\mid \mid (R_i^T) \mid \mid )^2$? I get that the $i^{th}$ term is non-zero, which gives us the contradiction, but not sure why it can be written that way.

Comment: $AX = BX \iff (A-B)X = 0$ for all $X \in F^n$. Now take $C= A-B$ for which we get $CX= 0$ for all $X \in F^n$. By above proof it gives us $C= 0$ that is $A= B$. The notation $(\mid \mid (R_i^T) \mid \mid )^2$ means inner product of $R_i$ with $R_i$.

Answer (score 2):

1. This proves uniqueness because it states that if two linear transformations coincide on all vectors, *i.e.* $\varphi_{1}(x)=\varphi_{2}(x)$ for all $x$, or equivalently $A_{1}x=A_{2}x$ for all $x$, then $A_{1}=A_{2}$ - so there is one choice of matrix for each transformation.
2. Why not using the column trick?

Comment: Thanks again. Makes sense. The column trick seemed too... clever (perhaps it's because this is first time I'm learning this subject), so I was hoping there would be another proof I could use to consolidate it. That's why I tagged it combinatorics as well, as there always seems to be a counting argument for bijections.

Comment: The column trick shows up a lot in linear algebra. It's a good trick to keep in mind. As for counting arguments, notice that for an infinite field $\mathbb{F}$ the set of all matrices $M_{nm}\left(\mathbb{F}\right)$ is not countable, so those kind of claims fail.